# Text still visible from lower parent element

Tags: html, css

I have two elements, an anchor and its pseudo-element. In the code snippet below, the pseudo-element is positioned behind its parent element. When it is hovered, the pseudo-element scales.

```css
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px;
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn-white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #777;
}

.btn::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
} 

.btn-white::after {
    background-color: red;
}

.btn:hover::after {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Example</a>
```

I know that when the button is not hovered, the pseudo-element is below the parent because they are in the same stacking context, and the pseudo-element has a z-index of -1. However, when the button is hovered, they are in different stacking contexts due to the parent using the transform property. Therefore, the pseudo-element covers the parent. However, the "Example" text from the parent element is still visible. Why is that?

Comment: Where is the pseudo element?

Comment: It's behind the parent element. Let me put that in the description.

Answer (score 0):

There are three elements for the html. The `<a>` itself, the `::after` and the text node "Example". `::after` is a child to the `<a>`

In normal state, `<a>` is a positioned element but since z-index is not set, a new stacking context will not formed. `::after` is also an positioned element with z-index -1, it has a stacking context and stay under `<a>`. In this state, both `<a>` and `::after` under root stacking context.

When hover, transform is applied to `<a>`, a stacking context is formed. `::after` and "Example" text node will be confined under this stacking context. Text node has auto z-index, which is greater then `::after`'s -1. Text node will be render above `::after`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn:hover::after {
transform: scale(1.5);
z-index: 1;
```

}

I think this overrides the stacking order of the text